# Is there a way to construct a RegEx to exclude ASCII characters above or below a certain value?

Tags: c#, regex, replace

We have the need to limit the valid/allowable characters in a string.  The rules we were given are as follows:

- Spaces are replaced with underscore
- Length limited to 256 (compiler restriction)
- Must be between ASCII code 32 (space) and 126 (~), and...
- It cannot contain any of the following:

  - : (Colon)
  - ; (Semicolon)
  - , (comma)
  - ' (Single quote)
  - " (Double quote)
  - \t (Tab)
  - \n (New line)
  - \r (Carriage return)
  - \\ (Backslash)

Anything that doesn't meet the rules above should be replaced with an underscore. (The length rule we can simply trim to at the end, unless there is something in RegEx that will address that as well.)

Now I know how to state allowable characters by creating a class like this for say, alphanumeric characters ...

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]
```

...then using the inverse of that in a Replace call like this (note the leading carat)...

```
var cleanedString = RegEx.Replace(sourceString, "[^a-zA-Z0-9]", replacementString);
```

...but how can I handle both the range (the "must be between ' ' and '~'" condition) as well as the specifically excluded characters? Do you do it as an 'OR' operation like this?

```
var cleanedString = RegEx.Replace(sourceString, @"[^ -~]|[;:,'""\t\n\r\\]", replacementString);
```

Note: Is that how you start a range between ' ' (space) and '~'?  Not sure if I have to explicitly escape the space somehow.

More generally, and like the question's title asks, say the rule was it just had to be above 32, but there was no upper limit.  How can you specify such an open-ended range?

Comment: Rather than trying to shoehorn a regex into this, why not just do it with a loop through the string?

Comment: This has to be a RegEx. That's why it was asked as such.

Comment: If you don't feel like "taking an eighteen wheeler to go get milk", I suggest not using a regex in the first place. Also, for proper UNICODE support, be sure to look at `System.Globalization.StringInfo.GetTextElementEnumerator`

Answer (score 3):

The range of characters identified by the 3rd rule are known as the [ASCII printable characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).

You can use the expression `[\x20-\x7E]`.

You can also use the Unicode expression `\P{C}`.

The POSIX character class [:print:] seems appropriate, but doesn't seem to be supported by .NET's regular expressions; it didn't work when I tried it.

Reference:  http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html

Update:  Below is more of a solution for the OP's stated problem as a whole:

```
static string StripInvalidCharacters(string input)
{
    return new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"\s|[:;,'""\\]|\p{C}").Replace(input, "_");
}
```

*Note*: in practice, you would want to create the Regex object outside of this method so that you avoid re-creating it every time this method is called.

I've defined an expression that matches on the following conditions:

- Any space character (space, tab, return, or newline)
- One of these: colon, semi-colon, comma, single-quote, double-quote, backslash
- any control character.  Notice that I used lower-case p in the expression \p{C} instead of the upper-case P that I mentioned above in the original answer. This is because the upper-case P negates the {C} part, which means "all control characters" (reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx).  So the expression \P{C} basically means "anything that is *not* a control character", but in this code example, because I am replacing characters with an underscore, I want to match "any character that *is* a control character", so I use the \p{C} expression for that.

Answer (score 2):

**Note:** The following actually does the opposite of the requirement - finding the *allowed* characters. For the disallowed ones, yes, I'd go with the OR approach quoted in the question.

You can use a subtracted character class (supported in Microsoft.NET - note that Mono apparently has - or used to have - bugs in its handling of subtracted character classes):

**Version 1**

```
[\x21-\x7e-[\\:;,'"]]
```

Explanation:

- `[\x21-\x7e]` = characters between ASCII 33 (0x21) and 126 (0x7e).
- `-[\\:;,'"]` = except `\` (escaped), `:`, `;`, `,`, `'` and `"`.

In other words, `-[...]` inside a character class subtracts the characters specified.

The range already takes care of removing the space, tab, carriage return and newline, so no need to specify them separately.

And yes, as an alternative to `[\x20-\x7e]` you can use `[ -~]`. You don't need to escape the space. Remembering that we don't want the space anyway, the above could also be written:

**Version 2**

```
[!-~-[\\:;,'"]]
```

`!` (ASCII 33) to `~` (ASCII 126), except the characters in the subtracted character class.

Actually think I prefer the readability of Version 1.

Comment: Doesn't my 'Or' case above achieve the same thing but in a much more readable fashion?  i.e. `@"[^ -~]|[;:,'""\t\n\r\\]"` This says 'Match anything not in this range, or match any of these illegal characters'

Comment: Define "much more readable" when it comes to regex. ;-) Personally, there are few cases where I find *any* OR readable in a regex. In any event, your version (and the requirement, I guess, on second reading) does the opposite. It matches all the disallowed characters, while this one matches the allowed ones. Other than that, the main difference lies in the amount of backtracking needed for each. And that neither of the methods are suitable for doing the other one's job. ;-)

Comment: I'm still not following the need for backtracking at all here though.  Yes, mine matches any invalid character, but I could reverse that to match any valid character too.  I can also set it to match one or more instead of just one.  Again, not really sure what you're gaining from the backtracking feature here.  Can you elaborate?  May be too much for my needs, but it's still good to understand another's reasoning.

Comment: I'd like to see you reverse it to match any valid character, without making it unwieldy. The reverse of "character class OR character class" is "not character class AND not character class" - which you can't do as easily in standard regex. In the same way, the above cannot easily be reversed to NOT match the characters. They're the shortest, most readable, solution for each their problem. As for backtracking, it's overkill to bring into this, but the subtracted character class = one token, the OR = two - which means more steps, and backtracks, for each match for the OR (2) than the SCC (1).

Comment: Actually, look again.  It's '(*NOT* character class A) OR (character class B)'  In other words, I'm either looking for something that's 'Not in this range', or I'm looking for one of these specific illegal characters (since they are within the first-defined range).  Doing it that way sets it up to easily work with the Replace function, which is what we want.  My question, which I admit I strayed off of with the other things, was how do you define an open-ended range (i.e. any character greater than 32 with no upper limit, etc.) in RegEx.

Comment: I'd prefer replying in chat, since this is flooded with misunderstandings by now, and leads nowhere in terms of answering the original question.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can only do ranges on sets of characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9), not ranges of ascii representations .

I believe the way to go about this would be to transform the entire string to acii, and split match on (\&#[0-9]{2,3}\;), then test each.

Theoretically, you could just write a regex that explicitly matches each and every valid 256 length possibility.  Don't think you'd want to though...which begs the question, why regex in the first place?